# Fixing Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.ProjectData.ClearProjectError vbc compile error

Tags: vb.net

I have a simple vb.net project that is basically a script for a GTAV modification framework, called FiveM. that's not really important tho, so, FiveM has a c# runtime, using Mono. Since I know vb.net better than c# tho, I decided to try and use vb.net for a script, knowing they both compile to MSIL. Obviously, since the runtime is made for c#, it doesn't include the vb runtime dll (Microsoft.VisualBasic), so i had to compile my script using the /vbruntime- flag and /nostdlib /define:_MYTYPE=\"Empty\".
for simple scripts, it works fine, but now I'm facing a bigger challenge. so, here's my code:

```
Imports CitizenFX.Core.Native.API
Imports CitizenFX.Core
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports System

Namespace WarThunderVClient

Public Class WarThunderVClient
    Inherits BaseScript
    Private flightstate = 1
    Public Sub New()
       OnTick()
    End Sub
    Public Sub DrawPlaneHUD()
        Dim speed As Double = GetEntitySpeed(GetVehiclePedIsIn(PlayerPedId(), False)) * 1.943844492
        Dim altitude As Double = GetEntityCoords(PlayerPedId(), True).Z * 3.28084
        Dim heading As Double = GetEntityHeading(GetVehiclePedIsIn(PlayerPedId(), False))
        Dim verticalspeed As Double = GetEntityVelocity(GetVehiclePedIsIn(PlayerPedId(), False)).Z * 196.850394
        If speed < 40 Then speed = 0
        If speed > 200 Then speed = 200
        If verticalspeed > 2000 Or verticalspeed < -2000 Then verticalspeed = 2000
        If altitude < 0 Then altitude = 0
        If Not HasStreamedTextureDictLoaded("flightinstruments") Then
            RequestStreamedTextureDict("flightinstruments", True)
            While Not HasStreamedTextureDictLoaded("flightinstruments")
                Wait(1)
            End While
        End If
        DrawSprite("flightinstruments", "speedometer", 0.9, 0.9, 0.08, 0.08 * 1.77777778, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255)
        DrawSprite("flightinstruments", "speedometer_needle", 0.9, 0.9, 0.08, 0.08 * 1.77777778, ((speed - 20) / 20) * 36, 255, 255, 255, 255)
        DrawSprite("flightinstruments", "altimeter", 0.8, 0.9, 0.08, 0.08 * 1.77777778, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255)
        DrawSprite("flightinstruments", "altimeter-needle100", 0.8, 0.9, 0.08, 0.08 * 1.77777778, altitude / 100 * 36, 255, 255, 255, 255)
        DrawSprite("flightinstruments", "altimeter-needle1000", 0.8, 0.9, 0.08, 0.08 * 1.77777778, altitude / 1000 * 36, 255, 255, 255, 255)
        DrawSprite("flightinstruments", "altimeter-needle10000", 0.8, 0.9, 0.08, 0.08 * 1.77777778, altitude / 10000 * 36, 255, 255, 255, 255)
        DrawSprite("flightinstruments", "heading", 0.7, 0.9, 0.08, 0.08 * 1.77777778, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255)
        DrawSprite("flightinstruments", "heading_needle", 0.7, 0.9, 0.08, 0.08 * 1.77777778, heading, 255, 255, 255, 255)
        DrawSprite("flightinstruments", "verticalspeedometer", 0.6, 0.9, 0.08, 0.08 * 1.77777778, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255)
        DrawSprite("flightinstruments", "verticalspeedometer_needle", 0.6, 0.9, 0.08, 0.08 * 1.77777778, 270 + (verticalspeed / 1000 * 90), 255, 255, 255, 255)
    End Sub
    Public Sub DrawHelp(text As String, isloop As Integer, isbeep As Integer, isshape As Integer)
        If Not IsHelpMessageOnScreen() Then
            SetTextComponentFormat("STRING")
            AddTextComponentString(text)
            DisplayHelpTextFromStringLabel(0, isloop, isbeep, isshape)
        End If
    End Sub
    Public Async Sub OnTick()
        While True
            If IsPedInAnyPlane(PlayerPedId()) Then
                If flightstate.Equals(1) Then
                    SetVehicleEngineOn(GetVehiclePedIsIn(PlayerPedId(), False), False, False, False)
                End If
                If Not GetIsVehicleEngineRunning(GetVehiclePedIsIn(PlayerPedId(), False)) Then
                    DrawHelp("Press ~INPUT_DETONATE~ to perform an engine startup", 0, 1, -1)
                    If IsControlJustPressed(3, 47) Then
                        flightstate = 2
                        SetVehicleEngineOn(GetVehiclePedIsIn(PlayerPedId(), False), True, False, False)
                    End If
                End If
                DrawPlaneHUD()
            End If
            Await Delay(0)
        End While
    End Sub
End Class
 End Namespace
```

so, when compiling it with vbc using this command:

```
vbc /libpath:"C:\Users\admin\source\repos\basic-resource\BasicResourceClient\bin\Release" /reference:CitizenFX.Core.dll /novbruntimeref /target:library WarThunderVClient.vb /vbruntime- /noconfig /nostdlib /define:_MYTYPE=\"Empty\" /out:WarThunderVClient.net.dll /r:system.dll
```

it was initially outputting an error about the "=" operator:

> error BC35000: The requested operation is not available because the
>   'Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Operators.ConditionalCompareObjectEqual'
>   function of the runtime library is not defined.

Which I easily fixed by using the .Equals() method,
but now it's outputting another two errors which I have no ideas on how to fix:

> error BC35000: The requested operation is not available because the
>   run-time library
>   'Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.ProjectData.ClearProjectError'
>   function is not defined.

```
        Public Async Sub OnTick()
            While True
                If IsPedInAnyPlane(PlayerPedId()) Then
                    If flightstate.Equals(1) Then
                        SetVehicleEngineOn(GetVehiclePedIsIn(PlayerPedId(), False), False, False, False)
                        End If
                    If Not GetIsVehicleEngineRunning(GetVehiclePedIsIn(PlayerPedId(), False)) Then
                            DrawHelp("Press ~INPUT_DETONATE~ to perform an engine startup", 0, 1, -1)
                            If IsControlJustPressed(3, 47) Then
                            flightstate = 2
                            SetVehicleEngineOn(GetVehiclePedIsIn(PlayerPedId(), False), True, False, False)
                            End If
                    End If
                    DrawPlaneHUD()
                End If
                Await Delay(0)
            End While
        End Sub
```

> C:\Users\admin\Downloads\server\resources\gg\WarThunderVClient.vb(50)
>   : error BC35000: The requested operation is not available because the
>   run-time library
>   'Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.ProjectData.SetProjectError'
>   function is not defined.

```
        Public Async Sub OnTick()
            While True
                If IsPedInAnyPlane(PlayerPedId()) Then
                    If flightstate.Equals(1) Then
                        SetVehicleEngineOn(GetVehiclePedIsIn(PlayerPedId(), False), False, False, False)
                        End If
                    If Not GetIsVehicleEngineRunning(GetVehiclePedIsIn(PlayerPedId(), False)) Then
                            DrawHelp("Press ~INPUT_DETONATE~ to perform an engine startup", 0, 1, -1)
                            If IsControlJustPressed(3, 47) Then
                            flightstate = 2
                            SetVehicleEngineOn(GetVehiclePedIsIn(PlayerPedId(), False), True, False, False)
                            End If
                    End If
                    DrawPlaneHUD()
                End If
                Await Delay(0)
            End While
        End Sub
```

Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

`ProjectData.ClearProjectError` is used the so-called VB Application Framework.   A large portion of that framework is to support backward compatibility to VB6 language features like `On Error Resume Next` that no competent VB.Net programmer would use anyways.

Go to the Project Menu->ProjName Properties->Application Tab, and clear the check mark for "Enable Application Framework".  Change the "Startup Object" dropdown to "Sub Main".

You will then need to define a `Sub Main` as the entry point for you program.

```
Module Module1
    <STAThread>
    Sub Main(args As String())
        Application.EnableVisualStyles()
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(False)
        Application.Run(New Form1())
    End Sub
End Module
```